# amcharts that have no data in dynamic data provider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, amcharts, ammap

Gracefully handle amcharts that have no data. I want know if my dataProvider empty. When amcharts draw default null. How can I handle it dynamically?

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "none",
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": data,
    "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Income in millions, USD"
}]
```

I want to know how to handle it when the data is empty.

Comment: Please refer my jsfiddle link  :- http://jsfiddle.net/9m3ugmpx/2/    where i can put the charts .i want to also hide titles of the charts and axis line.  if data is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle it externally by checking if the dataset contains records before even rendering the chart.

```
if (data && data.length){
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "none",
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": data,
    "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Income in millions, USD"
  }]
} else {
   // display a message to the user that there is no data available
}
```

The AMCharts folks seemed to have neglected handling an empty data set being passed in.

Another option is to [create a dummy data point that displays a label on the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/8u6cK/). I haven't personally used this approach because I would rather just hide the graph entirely if it contains no data.